# How to move <li> bullet element to the right?

Tags: html, css

Look at this screenshot.
There is two

text which is on the right side.
I want to have the list-style (bullet) besides its elements but as you see they are far from together.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/do4WH.png)

Additionally want to move them in the top (exactly in front of the first 3 texts.

```css
.treeview-ul {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  text-align: left;
}

.li-right {
  text-align: right !important;
}
```

```html
<ul class="treeview-ul">
  <li><a href="setup-vpn-pptp-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
  <li><a href="setup-vpn-l2tp-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
  <li><a href="setup-vpn-sstp-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
  <div class="li-right">
    <li><a href="setup-vpn-openvpn-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
    <li><a href="setup-vpn-softether-windows">TEXT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Instead of adding the arrows to that pic, could you please show the expected result? It's not really clear to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to use `space-around` instead of `space-between` if you want some additional spacing.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /*justify-content: space-around;*/
}

.treeview-ul {
  margin: 0 1.5em
  text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <ul class="treeview-ul">
    <li><a href="setup-vpn-pptp-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
    <li><a href="setup-vpn-l2tp-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
    <li><a href="setup-vpn-sstp-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="treeview-ul">
    <li><a href="setup-vpn-openvpn-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
    <li><a href="setup-vpn-softether-windows">TEXT</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add `float: right` and it will align to the right.

```css
/* CSS: */

.treeview-ul {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  text-align: left;
}

.li-right {
  /*text-align: right !important;*/
  float: right; /* Add float right */
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML: -->

<ul class="treeview-ul">
  <li><a href="setup-vpn-pptp-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
  <li><a href="setup-vpn-l2tp-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
  <li><a href="setup-vpn-sstp-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>


  <div class="li-right">
    <li><a href="setup-vpn-openvpn-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
    <li><a href="setup-vpn-softether-windows">TEXT</a></li>
  </div>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is not a good practice to have a `DIV` inside a `UL`. You are better off using 2 `ULs` as shown below and `float` the second `UL` to the right. You can wrap both in a `DIV` if you want.

```css
/* CSS: */
.li-left {
  margin-left: 1.5em;
  text-align: left;
}

.li-right {
  float: right; 
  margin-right: 1.5em;
}
```

```html
<!-- HTML: -->

<ul class="li-left">
  <li><a href="setup-vpn-pptp-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
  <li><a href="setup-vpn-l2tp-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
  <li><a href="setup-vpn-sstp-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
</ul>

  <ul class="li-right">
    <li><a href="setup-vpn-openvpn-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
    <li><a href="setup-vpn-softether-windows">TEXT</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to do much with the code to indent that second level of list item. But you do need to change a few things.

The first CSS class can be removed, most of that is not addressing any styling that isn't present already in the standards.

The second thing to do is to change the DIV to a UL instead, this is what is creating the second level indentation list item.

Keeping that class name in place, all you need to do is add a negative margin-left to move the indentation back to where it lines up with the list item above.

```css
.li-right li {
  margin-left: -1.5em;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="setup-vpn-pptp-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
  <li><a href="setup-vpn-l2tp-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
  <li><a href="setup-vpn-sstp-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
  <ul class="li-right">
    <li><a href="setup-vpn-openvpn-windows-vista">TEXT</a></li>
    <li><a href="setup-vpn-softether-windows">TEXT</a></li>
  </ul>
</ul>
```